# Eclipse Plugin :java Editor

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I want to extend the functionality of the java editor.
Instead of creating a custom editor, I want to just expand the functionality of
Java editor.

Where do I start?

Kindly provide some insight into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two examples to look at are the AspectJ editor (for AJDT) and the Groovy editor (for Groovy-Eclipse).  Both do exact;y what you are describing.  They provide sub-classes of the Java editor specifically for their language.  It's not a simple task and before you begin, you should have a deep understanding of how the Eclipse plugin architecture works.

The source code for AJDT is available here:
http://git.eclipse.org/c/ajdt/org.eclipse.ajdt.git/tree/org.eclipse.ajdt.ui/src/org/eclipse/ajdt/internal/ui

The source code for groovy-eclipse is here:
https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse

Finally, you should have a good read of this article about the eclipse editor framework:
http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseEditors/article.html