# Associate java editor with java files in your custom plugin project

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm have a plugin for Eclipse that creates a non Java project. Everything is working fine for my plugin. Now I need to add some Java files to my non java project and capability to edit the java files using the default java editor. Since it is a non java project I can't use the Create a Java class wizard and even if I create a .java file it does not open in a JAVA editor.

Is there a way to create a Java class using default wizards and edit the java files using default Java editor for a non JAVA project.

I have seen these answers 
[Eclipse Plugin :java Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810188/eclipse-plugin-java-editor)
and I do not want to write a new java editor, I Just want to reuse if possible.

Comment: Why not make it a Java project - projects don't have to be just one type.

Comment: Yes that's an option but I will have to restructure everything that's why I thought of checking here first.

Comment: Does your plugin declare a dependency to `org.eclipse.jdt` at all? That'd be a prerequisite I guess.

Comment: @ greg -449 Can I add java nature to my project and all java wizards and editors will be available to my custom project ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Followed steps from below post and converted my custom project to a java project.Basically added a java nature to the project.

http://java85.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/normallywhen-we-want-to-create-java.html